# Diff for only one character

Tags: ubuntu, awk, diff

I'm new to ubuntu and coding. I'm having a problem because I have two files that contains almost identical words. They only differ by one character (I hope). My inputs are files like these

File 1:

```
AEEL00123-RA
AEEL00123-RB
AEEL00125-RA
(...)
```

File 2:

```
AEEL00123-PA
AEEL00123-PB
AEEL00125-PA
(...)
```

I need the output showing ONLY the Ps or the Rs because later I'm going to count these differences and my files have 29000 lines each. I need to confirm that there are 29000 differences and that they are ONLY the letter P or R

I expect the output to be like this:

```
P
P
P
P
```

Because then I would count it with wc -l or something like this.

Comment: It's hard to help with a programming problem if you don't specify a language tag and don't show the code you have so far.

Comment: Please add some code here, showing what you tried to do, what you expected to happen, and what actually happened, so that someone can help you with this.

Comment: This is not a great question for Stack Overflow, but it would be welcomed on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Sorry guys. It's my first time asking something around here. For now I just tried "diff file1 file2", but I don't know how it works exactly.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmp -l file1 file2 |\
awk '
    { count++ }
    !/( 12[02]){2}$/ { print "bogus change at position", $1 }
    END { print count, "total changes" }
'
```

- `cmp -l` compares two files and outputs any byte differences
- the `awk` script counts the changes and prints the total; it also prints a message for any changes that aren't **P** (120) or **R** (122)

Note that if the two files contain any line with unequal lengths (ie. insertion or deletion rather than substitution), you will get very verbose output as the alignment change will make almost every subsequent byte become a mismatch.